# Remove word and 2 next characters from string

Tags: javascript, string

I have an url string, for example:

```
url = http://example.com/page/2/?attr1=data1&attr2=data2
```

I need to remove 'page/2/' from url. Page number can be single didgit or multiple digit.

Comment: Great! Sounds like a fantastic application for regular expressions. Could you please show us what you have tried and what research you have done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var url = "http://example.com/page/2/?attr1=data1&attr2=data2";
var array = url.split('/');
array.splice(array.indexOf('page'), 2);
url = array.join('/');
console.log(url);
```

The code first splits the URL into different sections with `/` as the `delimiter` and then finds page and removes the next occurrence with page as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
var parser = document.createElement('a');
parser.href = 'http://example.com/page/2/?attr1=data1&attr2=data2';
parser.href.replace(parser.pathname, '/');

// "http://example.com/?attr1=data1&attr2=data2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested, but should replace occurrence of 'page/any_integer/' with nothing

`url.replace(/page\/[0-9]+\//g,"");`

Answer (score 0):

This is not very elegant but it's a one-liner:

```
    <script>    
var url = "http://example.com/page/2/?attr1=data1&attr2=data2";
    url = url.substring(0,url.indexOf('/page/')+1)+url.substring(url.indexOf('/page/')+6).substring(url.substring(url.indexOf('/page/')+6).indexOf('/')+1);
    alert(url);
    </script>
```